# How can I earn card drops on steam?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I played Deus Ex: Human Revolution (Director's Cut) for 43 hours and I have a total of 4 card drops. How can I earn rest of these cards. Also, I'm new to steam.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the top right corner of your screenshot, you will see "*No card drops remaining. [**How do I earn card drops?**](https://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq/)*"

> **Is there a limit to how many trading cards can drop?**
>   Most games will drop a number of cards equal to about half the number of cards in that game's set of cards. For example, Half-Life 2 has 8 cards in its set, you can receive 4 card drops by playing it. You'll need to collect the other half of the set from other community members. Try the beta group discussions, community market, barter with friends, and trade discussions. You can check how many drops you have remaining on your badges page.
>
> **How can I get a booster pack?** 
>   Once you have received all of your card drops, you become eligible for a booster pack, which is a set of 3 trading cards that may include both basic and foil cards. Booster packs are granted randomly to eligible users as more badges are crafted by members of the community. Make sure you log in to Steam each week to maintain eligibility.
>
> Once eligible, your Steam Level increases your rate of receiving a booster pack drop:
>
> - Level 10: +20% increase in your drop rate
> - Level 20: +40% increase in your drop rate
> - Level 30: +60% increase in your drop rate
> - Level 40: +80% increase in your drop rate
> - Level 50: +100% increase in your drop rate (i.e. the rate has doubled)
> - Etc.

In short: you can either find someone to trade cards with, you can buy cards from the Community Marketplace, or you can wait until you receive a booster pack for your game (this can take a *very* long time).

Comment: For games with an odd number of cards, the number of card drops is rounded up. In the case of *Deus Ex: Human Revolution*, the game has 9 cards, but 5 will drop (9/2 == 4.5, which is rounded up to 5).

Comment: Huh, I was pretty sure the number of cards was rounded up. As seen in the picture of the OP (he has one card double)

Comment: @Arperum. You are right. I'll correct my comment.

Comment: To expand on the ways of getting cards, you can also craft booster packs from gems, which can be obtained either through recycling items like emotes or profile backgrounds, or by buying a sack of gems from the community market. 

Keep in mind though that at the time of writing, this is more expensive than buying the cards outright as most booster packs require 600-1000 gems to craft, and a sack of 1000 gems is about £0.70, where as most cards tend to cost about £0.07 to £0.10. You also don't know what cards you will get from boosters, but there is a low chance you might get a foil.